# How to determine URL when parsing HTML from node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, request

I am using `node.js` to open a list of web pages and parse the `HTML` contents.

I supply the URLs inside the script as an array, then call request to retrieve the `HTML`, which I then parse with Cheerio.

The problem I have is that some webpages do not list the URL inside the `HTML` content.

So I want to determine the URL of the page that I am parsing from within my request callback.

Since request is asynchronous, I cannot rely on the outer loop (loops through the array of URL strings) to get the URL.

Any ideas?

```
var requestList = [ 'https://blahblah.com', 'https://blah2.com' ];
for (var i = 0; i < (requestList.length); i++) {  
  request(requestList[i], function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      ...
      // how can i determine the URL of this html body?
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try  some console logs to the parsing variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use instead [#Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use closure to capture the URL

```
requestList.forEach((url)=>{

    request(url, (err,res,html) => {
         console.log(url)
        // rest of code here...
    });
});
```

Why it works?

Closure captures all the references (that the current closure can reach by the scopes). it's a function that has its own memory (kind of)

For example, let's take a look at this code that
you could also do that with a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < (requestList.length); i++) {
    handleRequest(requestList[i]);
}

function handleRequest(url) {
    // scope a
    request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        // scope b, (closure)
        console.log(url);
        // rest of the code
    })
}
```

Since `scope b` captures the values it can reach, it will remember the `URL` variable

*using closures sometimes can be dangerous because you can have memory leaks (when closure points to something from outside and something from outside points to something in the closure)*

Comment: Right answer, but you should explain *why* this works, whereas a for loop does not.

Comment: @Brad you are right, but since op wrote that he understands it's async and the loop is sync (which is usually the part most of the people misses) I skipped that
I'll update my answer

Comment: @DanielKrom thank you this worked beautifully and makes so much sense!

Comment: @Brad thanks for suggesting the additional explanation too.